# Notation in a paper

Tags: notation

I'm looking at a paper from H Fuchs called Optimal Surface Reconstruction from Planar Contours dated 1977. It can be found [here](http://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=guhwcP8AAAAJ&citation_for_view=guhwcP8AAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C). On page 2 of the PDF (stamped as page 694) the notation $+_k$ is introduced to denote addition modulo k. I understand what this means. The paper continues with this paragraph:

[image: Extract from paper]

I am not fully clear when P is subscripted like in this example:

[image: Focused extract from paper]

Looks like $m$ is being superscripted with a $1$. Later in the paragraph it gets a $2$. $m$ is the number of points in a contour, but why the superscripted number? I wonder whether the notation needs a $+$ operator? Hope someone can assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like $P$ is subscripted with $i+_m1$, that is $i+1$ modulo $m$, and that interpretation seems to make sense in the context you've posted.

Comment: Eric, thank you. Your interpretation makes sense to me.